# GWT: Maximum response size

Tags: gwt, servlets

I'm having a problem in GWT 2.5. Whenever I call an async method on the remote service, I get a 'The response could not be deserialized' error. The async method returns a simple string. What causes the error is probably the size of the string: A method which returns a string of 70.000 characters fails, where a string with 60.000 characters does not.

My question is: does someone know how to deal with large return values in GWT? I guess I can always try to make this into a regular http servlet, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What's the exact error? (the _cause_ of the `IncompatibleRemoteServiceException` that has this error message) Also, "between 60,000 and 70,000" looks a lot like 65365 aka 64K.

Comment: @ThomasBroyer: I've added a copy/past of the stacktrace [here](http://pastebin.com/rgrgrzEB)

Comment: Huh, really, no causal chain? ("Caused by" in a printed stacktrace)

Comment: your right, forgot to add the print the clause in my onError hook. A new paste is [here](http://pastebin.com/VtjyBLAg)

Comment: There must be another cause: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0-rc1/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/ClientSerializationStreamReader.java#311 (see line 322). Those lines are interesting too: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0-rc1/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/impl/ClientSerializationStreamReader.java#225 Also, this is in DevMode, does it work in prod mode?

Comment: I've added the print trace [again](http://pastebin.com/FNG1zQSR). Should contain all causes now.
And you are right, I've tried the code in production mode, and it works fine... Also tried other browsers in dev mode, but problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a limitation of the JS Parser used in DevMode to decode RPC payloads, which thinks Java strings cannot be longer than 64K characters:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/dev/core/src/com/google/gwt/dev/js/rhino/Parser.java#1420

Feel to file a bug report on GWT.

Comment: thanks, just file a bug report [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7687)

Answer (score 0):

never tried sending such a long string. But as a hack you could just return string.split which will give you arrays.

Comment: Yup, guess this isnt an unsolvable problem. Would like to avoid such workarounds though